# Outlook strips URL hash from email

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010

Our app generates an email that includes a link with a hash fragment.

- When an Outlook 2010 user clicks the HTML link (within the `<a>` tag), the URL is opened but mysteriously *excludes* the hash fragment.
- If the user clicks the plain URL (that Outlook converts to a clickable link), the full URL opens correctly.

Here is the relevant code from our Rails app, if that helps:

```
mail(from: @message.from, to: @message.to, cc: @message.cc, bcc: @message.bcc, subject: @message.subject) do |format|
  format.html { render text: @message.body_text }
end
```

Email message (truncated; using Twitter URLs in place of our app URLs, which follow a similar pattern):

```html
Subject: Hello
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id='message_body_template'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/cnn" title="" target="">Click here</a> 
             to learn more.</p>
          <p>Plain text link: http://twitter.com/#!/cnn</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

<kbd>Click here</kbd> opens the Twitter home page, while the plain text "link" opens CNN's Twitter page. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Yes we just noticed this today in some versions of Outlook.  Google brought me here so it's good to know others have also faced this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is unrelated to what back-end you use.  It appears that (frustratingly) some versions of Outlook strip the hash portion of URLs.

My solution was to **email a modified version of the link *without the hash*, and then redirect it to where it's supposed to go**.

When I had the same issue in Laravel + Backbone I performed the redirect using this code in `routes.php` (equivalent to `routes.rb` in Rails):

```php
// Redirect /password-reset/XYZ to #/password-reset/XYZ
Route::get('/password-reset/{any}', function() {
    $url = Request::url();         // Get full URL
    $path = Request::path();       // Get portion of URL after the domain name
    return Redirect::to(str_replace($path, "#", $url) . $path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had faced this issue, when I set the URL without any protocol. Later I tried adding the protocol to the URL and it began working properly.

I was creating the mail body part in the `JS` itself. Below is the initial code.

`var link = window.location.host+'/#/somepage';`

The working code.

`var link = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host+'/#/somepage';`

I hope this may help someone, who face the similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to change how Outlook handles the link, but you can simply use https://twitter.com/cnn and twitter will then redirect to https://twitter.com/#!/cnn

Comment: I should have been more clear – I substituted our app's URLs with Twitter URLs in the example, since they both follow the same pattern and exhibit the same behavior. We will likely need to modify our server-side code (luckily it's just a handful of URLs), but I was posting here mainly to see if this is a known issue in Outlook and whether there was a workaround.

Comment: @MartinGordon same problem here.  Did you find a way to keep Outlook from stripping the hash?

Comment: That's like asking, is there a way to make Microsoft adhere to standards and/or reasonable expectations.  Solve that one.