# mail clients stripping part of angular url

Tags: angularjs, html-email

I am sending a signup activation email containing a signup confirmation url with a confirmation token that points to an angular front end app:

...
  `<a href="https://domain.com/#/confirm-signup?token=1234...">Activate</a>`
  ...

Note that the token is a JWT and is fairly long.

This works find for most users, but for some clicking on the link takes them to `https://domain/com` only without the `confirm-signup?token=...`

It seems as though the mail client may be stripping off everything after the `#`, but I can't find any evidence of others having this problem, nor can I reproduce it.

My best guess so far is that some mail clients are seeing the `#` and somehow treating the trailing part as an internal anchor and stripping it...?

Has anyone else encountered this sort of problem? If so, have you found any solution short of replacing the whole mechanism with something else?

Comment: Yes i have encountered this issue before because of the #, we where trying to link to a anchor on a landingpage..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clients treat the hash-link just fine. Others don't. There's a conversation about Outlook being dirty about this here: [Outlook strips URL hash from email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933471/outlook-strips-url-hash-from-email)

What we did to resolve this at our company is simply create a handler on our server that redirects. Your email link would become `http://domain.com/email-link?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F%23%2Fconfirm-signup%3Ftoken%3D1234` and your server side script would grab the query param `url` and immediately trigger a redirect.

You'd need to make sure that you find all links in your emails and replace them. Here's a PHP function for that, but you could do this in whatever backend language you're using. Regex here may be helpful at least.

```
function replaceLinks($html,$hash) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/<a [^>]*href=[\"\']{1}(.+?)[\"\\\']{1}/', function($matches) use ($hash) {
        return str_replace($matches[1],"http://domain.com/email-link?url=".rawurlencode($matches[1]),$matches[0]);
  }, $html);
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this is the most reliable solution. In the short term we've gone with using a shortened link, but that brings it's own problems in terms of being frowned upon by gmail etc. Our current angular app doesn't have a server-side component, so this solution would be a bit of a pain for us to implement.

Comment: @PeterWhitfield you could actually pretty easily setup the redirect script on the frontend too by just looking at the query params and then redirecting with `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have encountered this issue before because of the #, I was trying to link to a anchor on a landingpage.. My solution ended up using a short.url service to "hide" the # from the html e.g. https://goo.gl/

Comment: were you using just a local anchor (ie: `href="#..."`)? Campaign Monitor have a post about variable behaviour in this case and I'm suspecting that for some clients it goes beyond just anchors staring with `#` and sometimes includes absolute urls which include a `#` somewhere in the string

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)!

A lot of times when your href gets parsed (by angular in this case) it doesn't handle the special characters right, or strips them. Find your problem characters and replace them with `%3F` for ?, `%26` for &, and `%23` for #. The rest are in a chart in the link.

Once the encoded address hits the browser the url will be decoded in your url bar.